# Cannot remove Docker container with status "Created"

Tags: docker

While trying to build docker image to my application, somehow I accidentally create 2 containers with status `Created`.

```
$ docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
597a3d226a08        2eba970a4fc8          "entrypoint.sh"          43 hours ago        Created                                        pedantic_almeida
bae7a9324bc8        b0898d035451          "entrypoint.sh"          43 hours ago        Created                                        zen_franklin
```

The problem is I cannot do anything with these containers. `docker rm/restart/inspect <container-id>` all hangs up indefinitely with no message printed. However, starting new container from these 2 images work fine.

So my question is how to remove these 2 containers? Please tell me if you need any additional information.

---

Docker version: `18.03.0-ce`.

Comment: I don't know if this works with containers in "created" state, please give a try to `docker kill` you can get more info running `docker kill --help`. Once you kill the containers and bring them into "exited" state, you'll be able to remove them.

Comment: @Mark It's not running so I cannot kill it. `Cannot kill container: bae7a9324bc8: Container ... is not running`.

Comment: Yep, I cannot reproduce a container hung in "created" state easily, but I have another idea that you can try: `docker container prune --force`. This will remove all stopped containers, so be careful.

Comment: @Mark thanks, it works. I tried `docker system prune` before but it did not work. Not sure what are the differences between 2 commands. Btw, you can write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Great! Happy we figured it out. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the below command to remove the two containers hung in "created" state:

`docker container prune --force`

**This will remove all stopped containers, so be careful!**

Answer (score 1):

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
docker rm $(docker ps -q -f 'status=created')
```

After execution of the above commands, restart docker by,

```
service docker restart
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, it still hung up in `docker rm` command. Also, no volume is associated with these containers.